# SQL Server - Convert datetime to JSON date format

Tags: json, sql-server, type-conversion, sqldatetime

How can I convert SQL `smalldatetime` or `datetime` like this:

```
select cast(getdate() as smalldatetime)
```

To JSON format like this:

```
/Date(1576278000000+0100)/
```

Comment: why do you need to `cast(getdate() as datetime)` ? `getdate()` returns `datetime` data type

Comment: Perhaps you need to generate this UNIX timestamp with a statement like: `SELECT CONCAT('/Date(',DATEDIFF_BIG(ms, DATEFROMPARTS(1970, 1, 1), GETDATE()), ')/') AS DateTime`.

Comment: Looks good, just need to add time offset?

Answer (score 0):

I just find this post in another issue like you got it.
Maybe it would work for you

```js
"render": function ( data, type, row ) {
  var fecha = new Date(parseInt(data.match(/\d+/)[0]));                
  return fecha.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + fecha.getDate() + '/' + fecha.getFullYear();;
 },
 "targets": 0
```

and this is the link that I found
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125686/convertir-fecha-en-javascript